# Substring the last digits of a numeric variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a numeric variable in SAS and I am struggling to extract the last digits of it. I tried using `substr` but it only handles `char` variables. The variable I have sometimes has 3 or 4 digits.

Example

```
1234
 237
 754
9000
```

In these cases I need to extract

```
34
37
54
00
```

And store them as a new numeric variable. I tried the code bellow in a `proc sql` statement but it returns and error. Can someone help me?

```
 Var2 =   input(substr(put(var1), 1, length(put(var1))-1), 8.)
```

Comment: Use the `mod` function. i.e. `var2 = mod(var1,100)`.

Comment: If you want to use `substr` then the code would be `Var2 = input(substr(put(val,8.),length(put(val,8.))-1,2),8.);`

Comment: or put(mod(x,100),z2.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SUBSTRN()` works with numeric variables but it doesn't work well in this case because there's no easy way to specify the last two characters only. The `MOD()` function works well in this case, because you're essentially finding the remainder of 100. Since it looks like it's a character you want, you need to use PUT() to convert it to a character as well, with the Z2 format to keep the 0 and leading zeroes.

```
want = put(mod(value, 100), z2.);
```

Answer (score 0):

one more way is to use prxchange as shown below

```
data have;
input val1;
val2=  input(prxchange('s/^(.*)(\d{2})$/$2/', -1, trim(put(val1,8.))),best.);
format val2 z2.;
datalines;
1234
237
754
9000
40
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the reverse and substr functions as follow and then use the z2. format.

```
input(reverse(substr(reverse(strip(put(var1,best.))), 1,2)), 8.);
```